# MySQL: Im receiving Error 1365 only while using UPDATE SET

Tags: mysql, sql-update

When I use simple

```
select 

column_a / column_b 

from t
```

there is no problem.

but when I'm doing

```
UPDATE t 
SET division = (
column_a / column_b
);
```

it returns **Error Code: 1365. Division by 0.** What could be the possible reason of this ?

Comment: because column_b is 0. Show table structure and example data

Comment: @danblack isnt that also supposed to return error while doing simple select?

Comment: (column_b)+1 also returns error division by 0

Comment: @Strawberry updated my command. "keep it to yourself" is a bit aggressive imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because you have `0` in `column_b` in some rows.

In a `SELECT` query division by zero returns `NULL` as the result. But in an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` query it causes an error, unless you use the `IGNORE` keyword. With `IGNORE` it will set it to `NULL`.

```
UPDATE IGNORE t
SET division = column_a / column_b
```